# Cantor's theorem, unclear generalization

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Feferman and Barwise show [here (20MB pdf)](http://download.library1.org/get/5F13D93911EEA1D3A5588901FF96C218/%28Perspectives%20in%20Mathematical%20Logic%29%20J.%20Barwise%2C%20S.%20Feferman%20%28eds.%29-Model-theoretic%20logics-Springer%20%281985%29.pdf) (Feferman Barwise Model theretic logics, page 58) in the Theorem 4.3.1. that **Counatble partially isomorphic structures are isomorphic**. Then they claim in a Remark **We see from theorem 4.3.1. that**
$\cong_p$ **is strictly stronger than elementary equivalence.**
I do not see how this Remark follows from the theorem 4.3.1. which speaks only about **countable** structures (and so it is not in general strictly stronger) and at the same time not about elementary equivalence but about an **isomorphism**.

Comment: It's helpful to *not* put a link to a 20mb pdf file without referencing what "here" might even be.

Comment: This is a 1000 pages book with multiple writers, Barwise and Feferman are only the editors. Please put an accurate reference to the author, the chapter, and even the page. I don't see why anyone should bother with your question if they need to go through such terrible length even to find out what you're asking. I know that I'm done.

Comment: @user122424 because the theorem says 'partially isomorphic' implies 'isomorphic,' and you should already know 'isomorphic' is strictly stronger than 'elementarily equivalent'.

Comment: Ok. And what about **countable** part of this question?

Comment: Well countable elementarily equivalent structures need not be isomorphic, so partial isomorphism is strictly stronger (since it is in general stronger, and in this particular case strictly stronger) : am I missing something ?

Comment: @user122424 You also should know that 'partially isomorphic' implies 'elementarily equivalent' for all cardinalities; this is enough for the claim to hold. I don't think the authors are claiming strictness when you look only at uncountable structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: For additional clarity, here's a summary of the answer below:

- $\cong$ **always** implies $\cong_p$ and $\equiv$; this is trivial.
- $\cong_p$ **always** implies $\equiv$; this can be proved via the characterization of $\equiv$ via Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games.
- For **countable** structures, $\cong_p$ implies (hence by bulletpoint 1, is equivalent to) $\cong$; this is Cantor's argument.
- For **general** structures, $\cong_p$ is strictly weaker than $\cong$: that is, there are uncountable $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ such that $\mathcal{A}\not\cong\mathcal{B}$ but $\mathcal{A}\cong_p\mathcal{B}$. The example I give below is a pair of ordinals, but there are many others.

  - Note that this, together with the second bulletpoint, implies that $\equiv$ is strictly weaker than $\cong$ for general structures. In fact, $\equiv$ is strictly weaker than $\cong$ even for countable structures, via much simpler examples (e.g. the linear orders $\mathbb{N}$ vs. $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}$).

So in general, we have $$\cong\implies \cong_p\implies\equiv,$$ with no implications reversing; if we restrict to countable structures, we have $$\cong\iff\cong_p\implies\equiv$$ (and the "$\implies$" remains strict).

---

The text *(by Ebbinghaus, in a volume edited by Barwise and Feferman)* correct.

The fact that $\cong_p$ implies $\equiv$ is an immediate corollary of the stronger theorem that $\equiv$ is characterized by [**Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game) *(see Corollary 4.2.4 in Barwise/Feferman)*, the point being that any winning strategy for Duplicator in the "full back-and-forth game" associated to $\cong_p$ is automatically a winning strategy for Duplicator in each finite-length back-and-forth game.

*(If you're unfamiliar with the game description of $\cong_p$, let me know and I'll elaborate.)*

So $\cong_p$ implies $\equiv$. Meanwhile, there are elementarily equivalent structures which are not partially isomorphic: take any two elementarily equivalent countable non-isomorphic structures. So $\equiv$ does *not*imply $\cong_p$.

Putting these facts together shows that indeed **$\cong_p$ is strictly stronger than $\equiv$**. However, it does focus on countable structures in a possibly-unsatisfying way, and we can ask:

> Does $\cong_p$ properly strengthen $\equiv$ even for uncountable structures?

That is:

> Are there *uncountable* structures $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ which are elementarily equivalent but not partially isomorphic?

The answer to this question is again "yes," but the proof is less trivial. Off the top of my head, the simplest example is a pair of distinct uncountable ordinals which, when viewed as linear orders, are elementarily equivalent. (Such a pair must exist by a standard pigeonhole argument.) The key fact now is the following (which I believe is folklore):

- **Theorem**: no two distinct ordinals (again, viewed as linear orders) are partially isomorphic.

*If you prefer: $\cong_p$ is just $\cong$ when restricted to well-orderings. This is not too hard to prove, but let me know if you want me to add details here.*

Putting all this together, we get:

- **Corollary**: there are uncountable, elementary equivalent well-orderings which are not partially isomorphic.

Indeed, we can even demand that they have any prescribed uncountable cardinality: e.g. there are elementarily equivalent non-partially-isomorphic well-orderings $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ of cardinality $\aleph_2$ and $\aleph_\omega$, respectively. This takes a bit more thought, however.

---

Incidentally, the following theorem - I believe due to Barwise - may be of interest to you:

- **Theorem**: the following are equivalent:

  - $\mathcal{A}\cong_p\mathcal{B}$.
  - $\mathcal{A}\equiv_{\infty\omega}\mathcal{B}$ *(that is, they agree on all $\mathcal{L}_{\infty\omega}$-sentences).*
  - There is some generic extension of the universe in which $\mathcal{A}\cong\mathcal{B}$.
  - In every generic extension of the universe in which both $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are countable we have $\mathcal{A}\cong\mathcal{B}$.

The last two conditions, while quite useful, rely on the technique of [**forcing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)); if you're not familiar with forcing, you should ignore them for now.

Comment: I would like to know how $\cal A\cong_p B$ implies $\cal A\cong B$ for both countable and uncountable structures. I.e. how follows your "That is:" in Are there uncountable structures $\cal A,B$ which are elementarily equivalent but **not isomorphic**?

Comment: @user122424 You misread my answer. $\mathcal{A}\cong_p\mathcal{B}$ implies $\mathcal{A}\cong\mathcal{B}$ for countable structures, but not for uncountable ones. However, $\cong_p$ implies $\equiv$ for **all** structures. Yes, there are of course uncountable structures which are elementarily equivalent but not isomorphic (e.g. two uncountable pure sets of different cardinality). The situation is this: (1) Isomorphism is stronger than elementary equivalence in every cardinality. (2) Partial isomorphism is stronger than elementary equivalence in every cardinality. (cont'd)

Comment: (3) Partial isomorphism coincides with isomorphism on countable structures, but is weaker than isomorphism for uncountable structures. This addresses, as far as I can tell, every question you've asked; is there still a point which is unclear?

Comment: Incidentally, there are **many** examples of uncountable structures which are elementarily equivalent but not isomorphic. E.g. take the language consisting of a single binary relation symbol $E$, and given an uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ let $A_\kappa$ be "countably many equivalence classes, each of size $\kappa$" and $B_\kappa$ be "$\kappa$-many equivalence classes, each countably infinite." $A_\kappa\equiv B_\kappa$ but $A_\kappa\not\cong B_\kappa$. *(Exercise: is $A_\kappa\cong_pB_\kappa$?)*

Comment: The basic interactions between elementary equivalence and isomorphism at all cardinalities are treated in standard model theory texts, and you should definitely make sure you're solid on these points before diving into Barwise/Feferman (which assumes a lot of background in classical model theory).

Comment: I didn't know that an article written by Ebbinghaus alone has "authors".

Comment: Also, I think the $\implies$ in your edit on the top are backwards. You write $\equiv\implies\cong$, which is certainly the other way around than what you say a few lines earlier.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh goodness. Fixed.

Comment: Ebbinghaus is still plural, I see. Is it a "royal we" kind of thing?

Comment: (Let me clarify the point about Ebbinghaus. The OP is *very* lazy when it comes to an accurate reference. Barwise and Feferman are the editors, and this is a multiple-author handbook. This specific question is about the chapter written by Ebbinghaus. There are not "authors" there is only "Ebbinghaus".)

Comment: @NoahSchweber It is all clear now except for your $E$ is $A_\kappa \cong_p B_\kappa$. How do I prove this? Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Also your "That is:" should read Are there *uncountable* structures $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ which are elementarily equivalent but not **partially** isomorphic?

Comment: @user122424 Whoops, good catch! Fixed. Meanwhile, the easiest way to prove that $A_\kappa\cong_pB_\kappa$ is via the game characterization: find a winning strategy for Duplicator. Start with the simpler problem of showing that "Two countably infinite equivalence classes" is $\cong_p$ to "Two uncountable equivalence classes." *(If you're familiar with forcing, you can nuke this problem by noting that there is a forcing extension in which $A_\kappa\cong B_\kappa$ and then applying bulletpoint 3 of the theorem at the end of my answer.)* This is similar (in spirit) to the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem.

Comment: Interesting! What is the idea for proving (iii) implies (i) in the last Theorem?
I think the converse should be easy. Just take some set $I$ of finite partial maps $f:A\to B$ that witnesses $A\cong_p B$ ordered by inclusion. Then from the back and forth property the sets $D_a$ ($D_b$) of maps with $a\in dom(f)$ ($b\in ran(f)$) are dense. So the union of a generic filter is an iso, right?

Comment: @Achilles If you already know that $\equiv_p$ and $\equiv_{\infty\omega}$ coincide, then you can argue as follows: certainly isomorphism implies $\equiv_{\infty\omega}$, so for each $\varphi\in \mathcal{L}_{\infty\omega}^{V}$ we have $V[G]\models\mathcal{A}\models\varphi\iff\mathcal{B}\models\varphi$. Now it's not hard to show that satisfaction of $\mathcal{L}_{\infty\omega}^V$-sentences is absolute between $V$ and $V[G]$, so $(\mathcal{A}\equiv_{\infty\omega}\mathcal{B})^V$.